# Simulate Python interactive mode

Tags: python, read-eval-print-loop, simulate

Im writing a private online Python interpreter for [VK](http://vk.com), which would closely simulate IDLE console. Only me and some people in whitelist would be able to use this feature, no unsafe code which can harm my server. But I have a little problem. For example, I send the string with code `def foo():`, and I dont want to get `SyntaxError` but continue defining function line by line without writing long strings with use of `\n`. `exec()` and `eval()` doesn't suit me in that case. What should I use to get desired effect? Sorry if duplicate, still dont get it from similar questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Python standard library provides the [`code`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/code.html) and [`codeop`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codeop.html) modules to help you with this. The `code` module just straight-up simulates the standard interactive interpreter:

```
import code
code.interact()
```

It also provides a few facilities for more detailed control and customization of how it works.

If you want to build things up from more basic components, the `codeop` module provides a command compiler that remembers `__future__` statements and recognizes incomplete commands:

```
import codeop
compiler = codeop.CommandCompiler()

try:
    codeobject = compiler(some_source_string)
    # codeobject is an exec-utable code object if some_source_string was a
    # complete command, or None if the command is incomplete.
except (SyntaxError, OverflowError, ValueError):
    # If some_source_string is invalid, we end up here.
    # OverflowError and ValueError can occur in some cases involving invalid literals.
```

Answer (score 2):

It boils down to reading input, then

```
exec <code> in globals,locals
```

in an infinite loop.

See e.g. [`IPython.frontend.terminal.console.interactiveshell.TerminalInteractiveSh
ell.mainloop()`](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/terminal/interactiveshell.py#L444).

Continuation detection is done in [`inputsplitter.push_accepts_more()`](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/core/inputsplitter.py#L330) by trying `ast.parse()`.

Actually, IPython already has an interactive web console called [Jupyter Notebook](https://ipython.org/notebook.html), so your best bet should be to reuse it.